# Angular 11 : error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object' but everything works fine

Tags: angular, typescript

So I used an API to get some pictures from it and add them to the slider.

Everything works the way it should but there is just this annoying error :DD don't know what is the problem.
I have this error in terminal

src/app/main-components/main-page/main-page.component.ts:21:34 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'

```
generateDataInCarousel() {
    let api = 'some Api'
    this.webworker.getDataFromApi(api).subscribe(respond => {
      for (let i = 0; i < respond.data.length; i++) {
        this.images.push(respond.data[i])
      }
    })
  }
```

any ideas what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typescript error because `httpClient` returns an `Object`. You can either typecast to any in the httpClient call or change your code to

```typescript
generateDataInCarousel() {
    let api = 'some Api'
    this.webworker.getDataFromApi(api).subscribe((respond: any)=> {
      for (let i = 0; i < respond.data.length; i++) {
        this.images.push(respond.data[i])
      }
    })
  }
```